# How to set the same style for all views but change only one prop for some

Tags: react-native

Two views:

```
<View style={styles.rectangle}/>
<View style={styles.rectangle}/>
```

I have these two rectangles that have a rectangle styling. I want to set custom flex for each of them, say the first one flex:2, second flex:5. How to achieve this without writing styles rectangle_flex_2 and rectangle_flex_5?

```
rectangle: {
    borderRadius: (5),
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF00',
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<View style={[styles.rectangle, { flex: 2 } ]}/>
<View style={[styles.rectangle, { flex: 5 } ]}/>
```

Here you are passing an array of style objects, the second object automatically overrides duplicate styles of the first one.